# Distance Calculation in NS-3

Tags: ns-3

I need to calculate the distance between the nodes and display them in either in terminal or text file.

I have complied the program using the function `GetDistanceFrom();`

```
double 
ns3::MobilityModel::GetDistanceFrom (Ptr<const MobilityModel> other) const
{
  Vector oPosition = other->DoGetPosition ();
  Vector position = DoGetPosition ();
  return CalculateDistance (position, oPosition);
}
```

I have used the above functions in my program but I don't know how to display them.

Answer (score 0):

A standard `std::cout` or the ns3`NS_LOG' should print you the information you want. See the logging section in the manual [here](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/logging.html)

Comment: Can you show me a sample code for calculating the distance between multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the distance between two nodes you need to access the `MobilityModel` in each node.

Here is an example:

```
Ptr<MobilityModel> model1 = node1->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
Ptr<MobilityModel> model2 = node2->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
double distance = model1->GetDistanceFrom (model2);
```

And this is how you print:

```
NS_LOG_DEBUG("Distance = " << distance);
```

For the log to appear you must enable loggin. So if you have a component named "MyComp":

```
NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("MyComp");
```

you enable loggin using:

```
LogComponentEnable ("MyComp", LOG_LEVEL_ALL);
```